# How to integrate a custom landing page on wordpress?

Tags: web, wordpress-theming

I basically created a wordpress site also i created a landing page that looks nothing like the wordpress site its already fully codeded in html/css now i was wondering how i would make it the wordpress home page

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to create a wordpress theme ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using wordpress 3+ You can do the following.

1. Save your html into your theme dir as a php page, name it something like template-home.php
2. Add the following to the top of that page /* Template Name: Custom Homepage */
3. Create a new page inside wordpress. Name it anything you like such as "Static Home"
4. In the right sidebar under "Page Attributes" there should be a dropdown containing your "Custom Homepage" template. Select it and save.
5. Go to Settings -> Reading. Check the "A static page" under "Front page displays:" and select your page that you made in step 3. Your static page should now be the homepage.

More here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: how can i use the default front-page.php as the Post Page