# Subbing home page total different to theme on WordPress Genesis Child Theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm about to do this on a Genesis child theme. I *really* tried picking a theme my client liked, but out of the blue with the project nearly finished they sprung their own artwork on me and want it for the homepage. So I had the site nearly up, and she sent me her own artwork that she wants to be the homepage. It's a full page and would have a different background than the rest of the site, no sidebars or widgeted areas, just three buttons.

Here is the solution I've found for this.

[How to integrate a custom landing page on wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860947/how-to-integrate-a-custom-landing-page-on-wordpress/5890227#5890227)

Will I need to add this solution back in with every upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not. Custom page templates is standard WP functionality. You should only set appropriate template for the home page.